What is required to make Spring Boot serve index.html without including it explicitly in the URL?
I have added a file named index.html to src/main/resources/static/admin/.  If I attempt to access it using the URL http://localhost:8080/admin/ I get an error message indicating there is no static resource /admin/.  Using http://localhost:8080/admin/index.html works correctly.
In Serve index.html implicitly with Spring Boot a suggestion is made to add code that look like this:
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addViewController("/admin")
            .setViewName("redirect:/admin/index.html");
        registry
            .addViewController("/admin/")
            .setViewName("redirect:/admin/index.html");
    }
}

This works, but other resources I find seem to indicate this shouldn't be necessary.
I have seen Spring Boot not serving static content which mentions not including @EnableWebMvc which I am not doing.
I do have several controllers annotated with @RestController which all specify paths starting with /api in their @RequestMapping annotation, so it doesn't seem like those controllers are interfering with serving the content in src/main/resources/static.  Even if I comment out the @RestController annotations on my controllers, the index.html file is not served automatically.
Is it expected behavior to have to add the @Configuration I've shown to have index.html served without including it in the URL?
